# maximize with assumptions on the parameters

Tags: simplifying-expressions, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to maximize a function of two endogenous variables (*Lf* and *Lo*), where I have two exogenous parameters (*T* and *p*), which are positive. All variables should be real. I do it as following:

```
maxFo = Maximize[{Sqrt[24 - Lf - Lo] + Lo +  Sqrt[Lf] p Sqrt[T], 
         {Lf >= 0, Lf + Lo <= 24, 0 <= Lo <= 5,  T> 0, p > 0}}, 
         {Lf, Lo}, 
         Reals];
```

I have a difficulties understanding several points:

1. `Maximize[]` returns a piecewise function that contains assumptions like `p>0`, but I've already specified this was indeed the case in `Maximize[..., {..., p>0},...]`. Why then does it still contain assumptions like `p>0`?

I then use the `FullSimplify` function to re-enter my constraints:

```
FullSimplify[maxFo, {T > 0, p > 0, 
  Element[p, Reals], Element[T, Reals], Element[Lf, Reals]}]
```

And then, I face the issue:

2. The answer for Lf seems to contain a complex number (`...2 i p...`)? Why? I thought I specified both in `Maximize` and in `FullSimplify` I wanted real numbers? Is it wrong how I specify this in `FullSimplify`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

1) `Piecewise` functions are always on the form `{{val1, cond1}, {val2, cond2}, ...}` where the last `cond` is often `True` when the `Piecewise` is generated by a *Mathematica* built-in function such as `Maximize`. When *Mathematica* is the one generating the conditions, it will give necessary conditions for the expressions to be correct, such that the `Piecewise` function can be used as-is in further calculations. Just because you told `Maximize` that `p > 0` does not mean you cannot do e.g. `maxFo[[1]] /. {p -> -5, T -> 10}` at a later time, and the result of this would be wrong if *Mathematica* did not keep the condition `p > 0`.

2) Inspecting the solution after `FullSimplify` reveals that the `True` condition in the last line in `Lf` is actually equivalent to `T == 95/p^2`. Inserting this we find

```
Simplify[(95 + 2 I p Sqrt[T] + p^2 T)^2/(16 (I + p Sqrt[T])^2) /. T -> 95/p^2]
(* 95/4 *)
```

So `Lf` is in fact real here. I'm not sure why *Mathematica* does not simplify to this on its own, but I think it has something to do with the order in which it simplifies the parts of the `Piecewise`. Since the last condition is just `True` even before simplification, maybe it's hard for *Mathematica* to recognize that the `True` actually corresponds to `T == 95/p^2`.

Comment: Great, thanks for the answer! answer to 1) totally clarified, the one to 2) almost did, although it introduced a new confusion: while your code with `Simplify[... /.T->...]` gives a real, the same with `Simplify[... , T==...]` gives a complex number... what's happening? What's the difference (maybe I should ask on another post?). See: `Simplify[(95 + 2 I p Sqrt[T] + p^2 T)^2/(16 (I + p Sqrt[T])^2),  T == 95/p^2]`